# Scheme How to Take the first item in the List?

Tags: list, scheme

Say I want to take the first item of the lists `'(4 3 1) '(5 6 8)`

I want something like this

```
(first '(4 3 1) '(5 6 8))
```

should return me the first item

```
(4 3 1)
```

as result. Is there something like this in scheme build-in function I can call ?

car doesn't work, as it only returns me the first item inside 1 list

list-ref doesn't work, same reason above, returns me 1 item inside the list

How can I do that? if I need to write it myself this first function ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`list-ref`](http://www.cs.grinnell.edu/~rebelsky/Courses/CS151/2007S/Readings/lists.html#listprocs) procedure to get an element from a list, using its index, for example:

```
(let ((l '((4 3 1) (5 6 8))))
  (list-ref l 0)) ; get the element at index 0
```

However if you only want the first element, you can use [`car`](http://www.scheme.com/tspl3/start.html#./start:s23):

```
(let ((l '((4 3 1) (5 6 8))))
  (car l))
```

Check the snippet running [here](http://codepad.org/2nHs70yk).

Answer (score 4):

You can use "." in function definition to take arbitrary number of arguments.

```
(define (first . args) (car args))
(first '(4 3 1) '(5 6 8))  ;; => (4 3 1)
```

Comment: Why not simply doing `(define first car)`?

Comment: `car` takes only 1 argument.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying too hard:

```
> (define (first a b) a)    
> (first '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
(1 2 3)
```

Comment: something like that works, but I guess I didn't put my whole problem here. it doesn't work when one of them have no value pass into. But thanks I think i got the idea :)

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I used scheme, but wouldn't you need to have the lists in their own list first

`(first (list '(4 3 1) '(5 6 8)))`

Comment: No, you don't. You can define a function that takes two parameters, each of which can be a list, and simply return the first one. You'd want to use a list of lists if (for example) you wanted, for some reason, to accept an arbitrary number of lists, and still return only the first of them.

Comment: Good point.  I was assuming the arbitrary number of lists as part of the requirements.